# Alamofire 4 and special characters in JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I've got a problem with special characters with Alamofire 4.
The JSON contains æ, ø and å and the browser shows them fine, also my previous solution using SwiftyJSON did.
Alamofire 4 shows something like this instead:

```
U00e6
```

Using this call:

```
Alamofire.request(specificURL, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
    print(response)
}
```

What to do to solve this?

Comment: are you sure that your json is properly encoded to utf8?

Comment: Yep, since the browser and my previous solution with SwiftyJSON shows it all right.

Comment: @Recusiwe Check my answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value) :

                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value as! [String:AnyObject]!{
                    print("JSON: ",JSON)
                    self.arrUser = Mapper<Users>().mapArray(JSONArray:JSON["user"] as! [[String : Any]])!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                //Print error
            }
    }
```

I got the issue that I have added æ in json response and try to print.

**Output:**

```
JSON:  Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x600000050320>(
{
    "email_address" = "testwts06@gmail.com";
     username = "testwts06 \U00e6";
},
{
    "email_address" = "testwts01@gmail.com";
    username = "testwts01 \U00eb";
},
{
    "email_address" = "testwts100@gmail.com";
    username = testwts100;
})
```

While displaying it display in correct format.

[image]

Comment: I cannot seem to find a member of the above? My specificURL is just a string.

Comment: When I set the encoding to JSONEncoding it doesn't print a single thing in this `Alamofire.request(specificURL, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result)
            }
        }
` I've checked the url in my browser, and it's all fine.

Comment: Try to use responseString instead of responseJSON.

Comment: Yes, it's all fine in the browser.

Comment: Add image of response.

Comment: From the browser?

Comment: Yes. Take image of browser response. and attach it with question.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3** update for Ekta's answer:

```
let encodedURL = specificURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems the typical serialization error due to wrong JSON encoding, probably your response status code is 3840.

**JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.**

You could try to convert the response data to correct UTF8 encoding:

```
let datastring = NSString(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.isoLatin1.rawValue)
let data = datastring!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
do {
     let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
     let jsonDic = object as! NSDictionary
     print("  ok, successfully converted..\(jsonDic)")
} catch let aError as Error {
     // print and handle aError 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple `String` extension that solves the issue:

```
extension String {
    func fixUnicode() -> String {
        var copy = self as NSString
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\\U([A-Z0-9]{4})", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)).reversed()
        matches.forEach {
            let char = copy.substring(with: $0.rangeAt(1))
            copy = copy.replacingCharacters(in: $0.range, with: String(UnicodeScalar(Int(char, radix: 16)!)!)) as NSString
        }
        return copy as String
    }
}
```