# crash when calling responseArray , get method with Alamofire & AlamofireObjectMaper

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am Facing Problem while Using AlamofireObjectMaper in Alamofire for fetching Array of my Categorey Object

**My Object :**

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Category: Mappable {

    public var iDCategory: Int?
    public var nameCategory: String?
    public var img: String?

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        iDCategory <- map["IDCategory"]
        nameCategory <- map["NameCategory"]
        img <- map["img"]
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

}
```

**and my call :**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ControllerSearch: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        Alamofire.request("http://pazirandegan.farhadarghavan.ir/api/ApiCategory")
            .responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Category]>) in
                for a in response.value!{
                    print(a.nameCategory!)
                }

        }

    }
}
```

**JsonArray:**

```
[{"IDCategory":2,"NameCategory":"رستوران و کافه","img":"/Upload/Images/eb0c3cd1-d911-43bb-bf59-9b736a98c49e.PNG"},{"IDCategory":3,"NameCategory":"پوشاک و البسه","img":"/Upload/Images/5da2b69a-3063-4b34-a74b-64ba8fb166c6.jpg"},{"IDCategory":4,"NameCategory":"پزشکی و سلامت","img":"/Upload/Images/a8bb9506-7c31-4ed0-b05b-41d9a760ab43.jpg"},{"IDCategory":5,"NameCategory":"فروشگاه و زنجیره ای","img":null},{"IDCategory":6,"NameCategory":"لوازم خانگی","img":null},{"IDCategory":7,"NameCategory":"زیبایی","img":null},{"IDCategory":8,"NameCategory":"فرهنگ و هنر","img":"/Upload/Images/43958739-0f41-489f-882c-65c2e2fd6eb1.jpg"},{"IDCategory":9,"NameCategory":"خودرو","img":null},{"IDCategory":10,"NameCategory":"کالای دیجیتال","img":null}]
```

No Errors are there and Output is Perfect, But my App Crashes

*Note : When Alamofire `responseString` is Used Everything Works Fine.*

Whats the Problem.

Comment: Please include your actual response to see why it cannot be parsed. And don't force unwrap `response.value` or `a.nameCategory`, one of those two is causing the issue.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i puted json array in question and i tested without for loop and still crash

Comment: So your code looks like this and it still crashes? `.responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Category]>) in print(response)
        }` Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and check the error.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i get this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "

Comment: I would give it a try to see if the problem might happen due to the arabic characters, so if you can, test your code with a JSON response mimicking this one, but without the arabic characters.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you, plz help to fix this :)
if it not working i must parse json manualy, i dont like do it

Comment: Did you check if its working with non arabic characters?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes and its working without crash

Comment: Have a look at highest voted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699642/alamofire-4-and-special-characters-in-json) question, I think you have the same problem, that your JSON is not .utf8 encoded